# Register Filter in CXF Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jax-rs, cxf

How can I register ContainerResponseFilter/ContainerRequestFilter in CXF? Like Jersey's ResourceConfig.

```
@Provider
@Priority(value = 2)
public class CorsResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
            throws IOException {

        System.out.println("filtered");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've enabled cxf be adding property `cxf.jaxrs.component-scan=true` then you Both resources and providers should be part of application context. Hence annotate with `@Service` or `@Component`.

```
@Component
@Provider
@Priority(value = 2)
public class CorsResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
            throws IOException {

        System.out.println("filtered");
    }

}
```

If you are enabling using classes scan make sure provider is part of packages you have given.

```
cxf.jaxrs.classes-scan=true
cxf.jaxrs.classes-scan-packages=yourpackage where provider is present.
```